# Python ternary operator and assignment in else

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, conditional-operator

Ternary operator is very useful, why it does not work in this particular case:

```
c="d"
d={}
d[c]+=1 if c in d else d[c]=1
```

It gives:

```
d[c]+=1 if c in d else d[c]=1
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't see nothing wrong here since the same thing without the ternary operator works:

```
c="d"
d={}
if c in d:
    d[c]+=1
else:
    d[c]=1
```

Comment: For this case, use a defaultdict. `from collections import defaultdict; d = defaultdict(int); d[c] += 1`.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: Why simulate a `Counter` with a `defaultdict` like that, when you can just use a `Counter`?

Comment: @abarnert: Force of habit? I always remember `defaultdict` first, because it came before `Counter` and because it's more general.

Comment: @abarnert: thanks, I always forget how cool Counter is

Comment: Can we at least call it the *[conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)*. It is **a** ternary operator, but so is the SQL `BETWEEN ... AND ...` expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ternary operator works on expressions, not statements. Assignment is a statement. Use a regular `if`/`else`.

Comment: Or use `defaultdict` and `d[c] += 1`. Or maybe `d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1`.

Comment: @Blender: Don't use `defaultdict(int)` to simulate a `Counter`. Just use `Counter` when you want one.

Comment: `Counter` gets no respect, I tell ya. A girl called it the other day and said "Come over, there's nobody home." It went over, nobody was home. I tell ya, it just can't get no respect.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to write this would be:

```
d[c] = (d[c] + 1) if c in d else 1
```

Comment: I think Blender's `d.get(c, 0)` is clearer (and also avoids lookup up `c` twice), but this works, and if the OP can understand it, that's good.